# Is it possible to merge (i.e. consolidate) 2 Android-Apps in the Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play

we have 2 applications in the Play Store in 2 different developer accounts who essentially do the same thing. Is it possible to "merge" those apps, i.e. remove app A from the store and notify users of app A there's an update, which installs app B? Otherwise we would lose all users from app A.

To clarify: I do NOT want to merge the code, I want to get rid of app A but not lose the users, they should update to app B.

Comment: Yes, you could update app A and create a toast on launch to display "App A shutting down. Download app B here: Play Store link." Or, you could display a pop-up on launch.

Comment: True, my question was rather if Google Play support it somehow. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Oh, well other than updating the description, I don't think there's any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Google Play does not currently support this feature, and requests by myself to do the same thing have not been answered or were rejected.

You need to find another way to move users to a new app, which is not easy if they are in the hundreds of thousands.